# Is it possible to upload excel (.xls) file to mssql in cake php?

Tags: php, sql-server, excel, cakephp, csv

I know most of the research recommend to upload in csv format which is more easier. Due to user requirement i need to upload in excel which is xls format into database, is it possible to do it in cake php? or use other method which is convert xls file to csv file then only upload?
Thank you!

I have try this out...and it shows undefined variable:ext and undefined index:Upload

```
$destination = realpath('../../app/webroot/uploads/excel/' . '/'); 
if(isset($_FILES['Upload']['XLS_File']))

$ext = substr($_FILES['Upload']['XLS_File'], strrpos($_FILES['Upload']['XLS_File'],   '.') + 1);
$path = $destination.'excel'.$ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Upload']['tmp_name'], $path);

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($path, true);

$temp = $data->dumptoarray();

if($temp)
{
foreach ($temp as $key=>$val)
{

$val['0'];
}
}
}
```

Comment: You have tried something, but what is the problem? Is `$temp` empty? Or is `$data` empty? What library are you using for the `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader()` class? Does `$_FILES` even contain a file or doesn't the upload work? Please be more specific and tell us what error you get, or what problem you have. We are willing to explain how to use a certain class if you have problems, but this is not a "script request community". **TL;DR** please improve your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the upload didn't work, it shows undefined variable:ext and undefined index:Upload, and the class is Version 2.21.actually i want to set the excel location (realpath) pointed to dropbox file, is it possible?

Comment: Just what I thought, so the problem is not that you can't read Excel, the problem is that the upload isn't working properly. Please `var_dump` (debug) the `$_FILES` variable and check what it contains.

Comment: Also, after your first `if()` there is no opening curly bracket: `{`. Is it possible the parser isn't running the if-block as you expect it to do? Meaning: maybe the `isset($_FILES['Upload']['XLS_File'])` condition is returning false, but because the if-block isn't set up properly, it tries to run the other code regardless.

Comment: thanks for the comment again, sorry, it also show error: The filename excel is not readable. I've added the curly bracket.The error occur still the same.

Comment: Can you update your code?

Comment: `$destination = realpath('../../app/webroot/uploads/excel/' . '/');` is weird also. Because it will result in `../../app/webroot/uploads/excel//`. Did you mean to use a comma (`,`) instead of a dot (`.`)?

Comment: thanks for your comment, i have solved the problem. I convert to csv format instead of using xls format to import.